# What would be the return type of a cartesian product of a multiset

Tags: data-structures, ruby

I am writing a Multiset in Ruby. The Union, Intersection operations where simple and return a MultiSet. But, I am not sure what the return type of the cartesian product should be, should I return an array of tuples? is that a good api?

```
 MultiSet.new([1,1]) * (MultiSet.new([1,2])
```

In Math it is

```
{1,1}*{1,2} = {(1,1),(1,1),(1,2),(1,2)}
```

Comment: Seems obvious that you should return a Multiset of tuples.

Comment: a mental block, learned math independent of programming long ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why you think the product of two multisets should be an array. It should obviously be a multiset. A multiset of ordered pairs, to be precise.

Ruby doesn't have a prebuilt representation of ordered pairs (or more generally tuples), so you could do one of two things:

- provide your own pair implementation
- do what `Hash#each` does and represent pairs as two-element arrays

I believe the second option is the more sensible one, so your return type should be a `MultiSet` of two-element `Array`s.

But I'm not convinced of your code example, either. In your example, you are implying that

```
MultiSet.new([1, 1]) * MultiSet.new([1, 2])
```

and

```
{1, 1} * {1, 2} = {(1, 1), (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 2)}
```

are the same thing, but they are not!

```
MultiSet.new([1, 1]) * MultiSet.new([1, 2])
```

is the same as

```
{[1, 1]} * {[1, 2]} = {([1, 1], [1, 2])}
```

and

```
{1, 1} * {1, 2} = {(1, 1), (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 2)}
```

is the same as

```
MultiSet.new(1, 1) * MultiSet.new(1, 2) == 
  MultiSet.new([1, 1], [1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 2])
```